# Ubuntu 16.04 on a 32GB USB stick won't boot

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, uefi

I used an Ubuntu Live USB installer to install Ubuntu on to a 32GB USB stick so that I could carry linux around with me in case I need it (I often find it useful for troubleshooting issues that Windows is unhelpful with).

I followed an answer on this site which told to first create a swap space as primary partition and then an Ext4 partition as a logical partition with mount point `/`, both of which were created "at the beginning" of the drive.

After completing the installation, I rebooted and found first of all that my 32 GB stick was not listed as UEFI by the BIOS boot select menu, and secondly when I selected it to attempt to boot, it simply failed and went straight to boot into Windows.

I am guessing I am missing a UEFI partition or something on the drive, but this was not made clear in any installation guides I have seen and I would have thought that the Ubuntu installer would have dealt with this for me? How does it work normally when I am installing to a regular SATA Disk?

Comment: I don't think the 32bit image offers UEFI support. That is likely the problem.

Comment: Is 32-bit still the default? I just downloaded the recommended version (no indication of what that was, just a big download button) and assumed it would be 64-bit.

Comment: @Luke Did you download the AMD64 or i386 image?

Comment: @PatrickNegus I downloaded the default image from this page. https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop Whatever that "Download" button gives me.

Comment: @Luke Ok, what CPU are you running? (run the command "cat /proc/cpuinfo")

Comment: @PatrickNegus It's an Intel i5 4670